# Вхождение подстроки в строку на определенное количество символов с конца

Tags: javascript, строки

Мне нужно определить, входит ли строка B в строку A на определенное количество символов с конца. В моем случае, это 6 символов:

Например,

```
строка А: 3897856787
строка B: 7856787
```

Если строка B входит в строку А, должно вернуть true, иначе - false.

Например,

```
строка А: 3897856787
строка B: 389785
```

False, тк совпадение с начала строки

Если,

```
строка А: 3897856787
строка B: 87
```

В таком случае должно вернуть false, тк вхождение всего 2 символов.

Подскажите, как изменить данное решение?

```
const isMatch = (str, match) => (( str.length > 5 ) ? match.indexOf(str) > -1 : false);

const match = '123456789'; // Строка A
const a = '123'; // Строка B
const b = '345678'; // Строка C

console.log(isMatch(a, match)) // false Строка A не содержит строку B
console.log(isMatch(b, match)) // true Строка A содержит строку С

// Кастом для внятности
console.log(isMatch('112233', '0011223344')) // true
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: @Igor Определить входит ли строка B в строку А на 5 символов с конца.

Comment: Мне непонятно, что это значит. Особенно "на 5 символов с конца".

Comment: это 100% дубликат, было неделю-две назад

Comment: @Igor 5 символов с конца, это означает, что должна быть проверка на совпадение символов с конца строки, если с начала - то должно вернуть false

Comment: @Denis так вроде же все правильно, только если поиск сначала строки необходимо исключить, надо изменить на 0 - `isMatch = (a, b) => a.length > 5 && b.indexOf(a) > 0;`

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg Спасибо!

Только почему данный кейс возвращает false, если мы проверяем на 5 символов с конца? ПО логике, должно вернуть true

const match = '972545751506'; // Строка A
const a = '0545751506'; // Строка B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень трудно понять чего вы хотите

```js
// Если строка не менее 6 символов, обрезаем 6 последних и составляем регулярку
// /.+123456/   - .+ это по вашему условию не должно быть совпадения в начале строки
const isMatch = ( a, b ) => a.length > 5 && ( new RegExp( '.+' + a.substring( a.length - 6 ) ) ).test( b );

// Это пример из вашего комментария, где как вы указали должно получиться TRUE
console.log( isMatch( '972545751506', '0545751506' ) ); // true
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!